# Spring Security 3.0.5 Custom Filter Issue

Tags: spring, spring-security

when I try to configure a new custom authentication filter using spring security 3.0.5 it calls the custom filter (XMLAuthenticationFilter) constructor at server startup and complains about not having an authenticationManager specified, see exception below.  The goal is to use form based and a custom based authentication...how does the XMLAuthenticationFilter.java hook into the AuthenticationManager and should the constructor get called at server startup?

**security-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dc" />
    <global-method-security />
    <http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/preregistered/*"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
            access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
        <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/**"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/registered/*"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
          <intercept-url
            pattern="/*"
           access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
            login-page="/auth/login.html"
            default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html" />
         <logout invalidate-session="true" 
              logout-success-url="/" 
              logout-url="/auth/logout.html"/>
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="ddddd"/>
        <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="xmlAuthenticationFilter"/>
    </http>
    <!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
    <authentication-manager alias="am">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="xmlAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
 <bean id="xmlAuthenticationFilter" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <bean id="xmlAuthenticationProvider" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationProvider"/>
</beans:beans>
```

**custom AuthenticationProvider:**

```
   import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider;
    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

    public class XMLAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider{

        @Override
        protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails arg0, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1) throws AuthenticationException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String arg0, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken arg1) throws AuthenticationException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**custom filter (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter):**

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

public class XMLAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter{
    public XMLAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/xml_security_check");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Exception**:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlAuthenticationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dc-context-api.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4521)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5004)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:4999)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an authentication-manager with alias "am", where are you setting the authenticationmanager-property in your filter? Maybe the the xml-configuration of *XMLAuthenticationFilter* should be something like:

```
<bean id="xmlAuthenticationFilter" class="com.dc.api.service.impl.XMLAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="am"/>
</bean>
```

I think the [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) is throwing the exception from its afterPropertiesSet-method (it should be visible in the nested stacktrace after the line *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified*). AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilters' documentation says the manager must be set:

> Authentication Process
>
> The filter
> requires that you set the
> *authenticationManager* property. An
> AuthenticationManager is required to
> process the authentication request
> tokens created by implementing
> classes.