# Spring Security authentication manager won't get picked up on custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to create a custom filter to take care of authentication, since I'm forced to use a combination of an AD and local database (arg!) to determine access rights.  I'm using the official docs, for this particular issue mostly [this part](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-manager).

However, when I run my server it is complaining about the AuthenticationManager being null, while I believe I am setting it in XML as covered [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447829/spring-security-3-0-5-custom-filter-issue). What am I missing here?

**The exception:**

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' defined in file [*snip*]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
```

**The XML: (with some simplified class names)**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan base-package="myapp" />

<!-- Spring Security Configuration. -->
<sec:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-denied-page="/denied.jsp">
    <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationFilter" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/404.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
</sec:http>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>
<bean id="myAuthenticationFilter" class="myapp.MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="myapp.MyAuthenticationProvider" />
```

**The Filter:**

```
@Component
public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
public AdminUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/login");
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    // stuff and:
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            login, request.getParameter("password")));
}
}
```

**The AuthenticationProvider:**

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // all the funky AD+DB code
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(final Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}
}
```

I am running Java 6, the latest Spring Security (3.1.4.RELEASE) and Spring (3.2.3.RELEASE) versions, running on a Tomcat v6 server. Different Spring versions do not appear to be a problem ([related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542545/can-i-use-new-spring-3-2-with-older-spring-security-3-0)). And if it would be a problem, having to run Spring 3.1.4 if you want to use Spring Security is just meh...

Some additional things I tried to no avail:

1. I tried ditching the `<sec:authentication-manager />` in favour of a normal bean, as mentioned [here (bottom answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104228/how-implement-spring-security-when-login-page-having-more-field-apart-from-user/16155696#16155696).
2. I tried adding bean id's, names, authentication-manager-refs in all sorts of combinations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah... I spot the basic error made by many in Spring. You have your bean `MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` defined in XML, which is correct. However you have it also annotated by `@Component` annotation, which means it is being picked and registered as another bean definition by *component scan*. And bean instance comming from this definition won't indeed have its `authenticationManager` dependency initalized.

**Just remove the `@Component` annotation in `MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and you should be OK.**

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thanks a ton. I can't believe I missed something like that.

Comment: I hope you won't *furiously yell and wave at the wall* for too long :D.